# Writing a program that will demo the $PS2 variable

Tags: command-line, bash, environment-variables

I've been customizing my terminal prompt, and found that it's possible to change the "secondary prompt". However, I have no way to test the changes I make to this one so I was wondering if a simple script could be written to test the new `$PS2`?

Comment: Put `"` (double quote) on the terminal and press **Enter**. As bash does not see the matching quote to close the string, it will show `PS2` to complete the multiline command.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From `man bash`:

```
   PS2    The value of this parameter is expanded as with PS1 and used  as
          the secondary prompt string.  The default is ``> ''.
```

The "secondary prompt string" is what is shown when you have multi-line input. For example:

```
$ echo 'foo
>bar'
```

The `>` shown above is `PS2`. If I were to change that, I would see it as soon as I tried any multi-line command:

```
$ PS2="%"
$ echo 'foo
%bar'
```

Ways to run multi-line commands include:

- Open quotes (single or double) and hit <kbd>enter</kbd> without closing them.
- Add a backslash to the end of a command and hit <kbd>enter</kbd>:

  ```
  $ echo foo \
  >
  ```
- Use a HEREDOC:

  ```
  $ echo <<<END  ## hit enter
  ```

As for doing it with a script, that's really not needed but you can simply write a script that prints `PS2`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
printf "PS2 : %s\n" "$PS2"
```

Comment: Your script doesn't show colored prompts and mine does ;-) `echo -e` or `printf` is needed to show escape characters correctly.